# How to migrate to Vite from Create-React-App?

Tags: reactjs, migration, create-react-app, vite, vite-reactjs

I am trying to migrate from CRA to Vite.

- I cloned the project from GitHub
- I removed 'react-scripts' from both 'scripts' and 'dependencies' section from package.json
- I ran this command: `yarn add vite @vitejs/plugin-react-refresh vite-plugin-svgr`
- I added **vite.config.js** to the root directory.

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import reactRefresh from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import svgrPlugin from "vite-plugin-svgr";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    outDir: "build",
  },
  plugins: [
    reactRefresh(),
    svgrPlugin({
      svgrOptions: {
        icon: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

- I installed all the dependencies using the command: `yarn`
- I moved the **index.html** to the root directory.
- I changed the **index.html** file. Now, It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />

    <!-- bootstrap css  -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- bootstrap js  -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root">
      <script type="module" src="/src/index.jsx"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- I renamed the **index.jsx** to **main.jsx**
- I made sure all the functional component has **.jsx** extension to their file name
- Finally i renamed the .env secret to `VITE_STRIPE` from **REACT_APP_STRIPE**

Then I ran this command: `yarn start`
But it shows:

> vite start
> Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.
>
> VITE v4.4.9  ready in 401 ms
>
> Local:   http://localhost:5173/
> Network: use --host to expose
> press h to show help

In http://localhost:5173/:
*This localhost page can’t be found*

You can see the code structure in [`GitHub`](https://github.com/Apu-Emdad/E-Mart-Client) at the commit: `vite integration failed` in `vite-integration` branch.

I would like to know what I did wrong and How can I successfully migrate from CRA to vite?

I tried

1. `yarn cache clean`
2. `yarn vite dev` . returns:

> yarn run v1.22.19
>
> $ C:\Apu\personal_project\E-Mart-Client-vite\E-Mart-Client\node_modules\.bin\vite dev
>
> failed to load config from C:\Apu\personal_project\E-Mart-Client-vite\E-Mart-Client\vite.config.js
>
> error when starting dev server:
>
> Error: Cannot find module '@vitejs/plugin-react'

3. `yarn add @vitejs/plugin-react-refresh`  again.
4. `yarn vite dev`  returns the same as number **2.**
5. The issue persists.